# Проблема с xhr запросами

Tags: javascript, mvc, asp.net-core, rest, xhr

Есть приложение - asp net core mvc с контроллером api (просто контроллер в котором содержаться post/get методы). Есть фронт, который вызывает эти методы с помощью xmlhttprequest. На локалке (когда разрабатывал и тестил) одинаково работали и get и post методы, после выкладки get методы работают но при вызове post 404 ошибка. При этом из postman'a все работает.

Контроллер выглядит примерно так

```
[Route("api")]
public class ApiController : Controller 
{
[HttpPost]
[Route("someMethod")]
 public JsonResult Method() { ... } 
}
```

js код который вызывает данный метод

```
function DoXhrPostJson(model, url) {
        var result = document.getElementById("container");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("POST", url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(model));

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                AddToResult(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                result.innerText = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
            }
        }
    }
```

Url похоже передается валидный, `http://some.site.ru/api/testing`. При запросе с postman по данному url все ок. Get методы работают без проблем. В чем может быть ошибка?

Cors разрешил так, в StartUp файле в ConfigureServices сделал `services.AddCors()`
Затем в
 configure `{
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в cors, добавил

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("host"));
        });
```

и `app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");`